# Footer not changing size when being opened in mobile browser in desktop mode

Tags: javascript, html, css

When i am opening my website in android, it looks preety good, but when i am opening it in desktop mode in android then the alignment and UI of whole website becomes delocalise and ugly (I have created my whole website with responsive units), and my footer doesn't change its size in desktop mode in android.
Here is the website
https://rohitkumar66.github.io/vivekanandaenglishschool

Can anyone give me suggestion what should i do?
I have used HTML, CSS, JS only

Comment: Your  mobileRedirect.js file is not found and gives 404 error. You can inspect errors  in  browser console.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not using different versions, i am using same site with different display sizes. Therefore mobileRedirect.js file is not present.